# Internet Explorer 11 - Different behavior on measuring percent?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a tricky problem which I have been unable to solve.

```js
$(".btn-nav").on("click tap", function() {
  $(".nav-container")
    .toggleClass("showNav hideNav")
    .removeClass("hidden");
  $(this).toggleClass("animated");
});
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100% -ms-content-zooming: none;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
  -webkit-content-zooming: none;
  content-zooming: none;
}
body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', arial, serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
button {
  z-index: 1070;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0
}
:focus {
  outline: none
}
::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0
}
.btn-nav:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
.btn-nav:hover .bar {
  background: #17BEBB
}
.bar {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 22% auto;
}
.btn-nav {
  z-index: 1070;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.8% 0;
  width: 3%;
  height: 4%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 2%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.btn-nav:focus {
  outline: none
}
.middle {
  margin: 0 auto
}
.bar {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}
.animated {
  z-index: 1070;
}
.animated .arrow-top-r {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  width: 55%;
}
.animated .arrow-middle-r {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(50%);
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
.animated .arrow-bottom-r {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button class="btn-nav">
    <div class="bar arrow-top-r"></div>
    <div class="bar arrow-middle-r"></div>
    <div class="bar arrow-bottom-r"></div>
  </button>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6t04y9wo/6/

As you can see, the top-left navigation button is shown differently between Chrome and IE.
I tried to get everything work in percent units to avoid incompatibility with 4k monitors (or very different resolutions) or zooming (which is really hard to avoid on a touchscreen-monitor+ windows).

As far as I can see, the `height` of the `button`element is measured really differently, and so the inner heights will be. I've tried many different settings for that, but I can't get it work and look good for both Chrome and Internet Explorer.

It seems that the `margin` here:

```
.bar {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 22% auto;
}
```

Is not correct, but I don't know how to fix it.

Maybe there is someone with some useful hints?

Comment: I've moved your Fiddle code into a Stack Snippet as Stack Overflow requires the code to be in the question itself (just in case the link were to die).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would appear to be due to IE not calculating the `height` of the `button` correctly.

When using `position: fixed;` the position and dimensions of the element should be calculated in relation to the initial containing block:

> Whereas the position and dimensions of an element with position:absolute are relative to its containing block, the position and dimensions of an element with position:fixed are always relative to the initial containing block. This is normally the viewport: the browser window or the paper’s page box.

*Fixed positioning (https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning)*

It appears that IE is sizing the button in relation to the `body`. As you are using percentage `height` and no `height` has been specified on `body` this will result in the `height` for the `button` being set as `auto`. This can be overcome by adding `height: 100%;` to `body` so that the `button`'s `height` can be calculated in relation to it.

The `height` of the bars in the `button` is set to `50%` which with the `padding` will mean they exceed the `height` of the `button`. To overcome this you should set `overflow: visible;` on the `button` to allow them to be visible.

There is also a small typo that you will want to fix:

```
height: 100% -ms-content-zooming: none;
```

Should be:

```
height: 100%; 
-ms-content-zooming: none;
```

You may also want to set a `min-height` and `min-width` to ensure the `button` shows when the viewport height is very small.

```js
$(".btn-nav").on("click tap", function() {
  $(".nav-container")
    .toggleClass("showNav hideNav")
    .removeClass("hidden");
  $(this).toggleClass("animated");
});
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  -ms-content-zooming: none;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
  -webkit-content-zooming: none;
  content-zooming: none;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', arial, serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
button {
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 1070;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0
}
:focus {
  outline: none
}
::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0
}
.btn-nav:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
.btn-nav:hover .bar {
  background: #17BEBB
}
.bar {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 22% auto;
}
.btn-nav {
  z-index: 1070;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.8% 0;
  width: 3%;
  height: 4%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 2%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  min-height: 20px;
  min-width: 50px;
}
.btn-nav:focus {
  outline: none
}
.middle {
  margin: 0 auto
}
.bar {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}
.animated {
  z-index: 1070;
}
.animated .arrow-top-r {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  width: 55%;
}
.animated .arrow-middle-r {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(50%);
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
.animated .arrow-bottom-r {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button class="btn-nav">
    <div class="bar arrow-top-r"></div>
    <div class="bar arrow-middle-r"></div>
    <div class="bar arrow-bottom-r"></div>
  </button>
</body>
```

Alternatively, you could use viewport units to specify the dimensions of the `button`.

```js
$(".btn-nav").on("click tap", function() {
  $(".nav-container")
    .toggleClass("showNav hideNav")
    .removeClass("hidden");
  $(this).toggleClass("animated");
});
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  -ms-content-zooming: none;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
  -webkit-content-zooming: none;
  content-zooming: none;
}
body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', arial, serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
button {
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 1070;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0
}
:focus {
  outline: none
}
::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0
}
.btn-nav:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
.btn-nav:hover .bar {
  background: #17BEBB
}
.bar {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 22% auto;
}
.btn-nav {
  z-index: 1070;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.8% 0;
  width: 4vh;
  height: 4vh;
  position: fixed;
  left: 2%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  min-height: 20px;
  min-width: 50px;
}
.btn-nav:focus {
  outline: none
}
.middle {
  margin: 0 auto
}
.bar {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}
.animated {
  z-index: 1070;
}
.animated .arrow-top-r {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg) translateY(180%);
  width: 55%;
}
.animated .arrow-middle-r {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(50%);
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
.animated .arrow-bottom-r {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-180%);
  width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button class="btn-nav">
    <div class="bar arrow-top-r"></div>
    <div class="bar arrow-middle-r"></div>
    <div class="bar arrow-bottom-r"></div>
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use pixels, 4k displays are scaled, my uhd notebook shows exactly the same page when I'm looking at a page with a 1200px width body.